# How to remove the first and last character in JObject in c#

Tags: trim

```
 string jsonstring = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict, Formatting.Indented);
        JObject json = JObject.Parse(jsonstring );
```

I am using this code  first and last character needs to be removed...whenever i am converting json string to jobject curly braces gets included in first and last character of the object  ...How should i remove this or is there any other way to convert json string to jobject

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Json starts and ends with curly braces

Comment: Without curly braces at the start and end, it won't be a valid json object.

Comment: its having extra curly braces...my object is {name:"10"} but its comming {{ name:"10"}} i am not able to trim jobject